# How do I add a string in a calculated field within Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

Im new to tableau, and trying to create basic viz:

I have created a calculated field that calculated the percent values of a vector within tableau

Repex:

```
Cast Total
1    10
2    10
3    10
```

sum(Cast/10*100)

but this gives me the literal values when I plot it in a tree map.
if I try to do

```
sum(Cast/10*100)+"%" or + "percent"
```

I get a syntax error.

Basically within the tree map I want to display it as 1"%" or 2% instead of it just written as 1 and 2.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your numerical expression in `STR()` to treat it as a string:

```
STR(SUM([Cast]/10*100)) + '%'
```